# Pushing onto github using ubuntu on windows and get error prompt telling me my login credentials are wrong when they aren't

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, github, repository, push

this is the code i entered into the ubuntu terminal to push onto my github project:

"git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/nessed/lmc-website1.git
git push -u origin main"

however, when the github login prompt comes up, the terminal gives me this error message:

'Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.'

Changing my password did not fix the problem. Git is also updated to the latest version. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How are you entering your credentials?

Answer (score 0):

> Changing my password did not fix the problem

When Git is asking for GitHub credentials, you should not use your GitHub account password, but a dedicated [classic PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic), with an [OAuth scope "`repo`"](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes).

Check your `git config --global credential.helper`.
It should be "`manager`" and, if not, install [Microsoft GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager).
That will cache your credentials (GitHub user account name and PAT/token)